# After fetching data from DRF ListAPIView, how do I get it into a form needed to perform a map() method on it?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I am serializing all instances of my model Recipe. The Django API view looks like this (ignore the random recipes):

```
[
    {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "marsh",
        "cooktime": "5",
        "ingredients": "marshmellow\r\nonion",
        "directions": "make the onion\r\neat the marsh\r\nenjoy",
        "created_date": "08/16/2020 20:56:09",
        "published_date": null,
        "picture": null,
        "author": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "title": "mac",
        "cooktime": "1",
        "ingredients": "mac\r\ncheese",
        "directions": "make cheddar\r\nadd mac and cheddar\r\nyes yes",
        "created_date": "08/16/2020 20:56:49",
        "published_date": null,
        "picture": null,
        "author": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 34,
        "title": "onion",
        "cooktime": "20",
        "ingredients": "onion\r\ncheddar\r\nmozz",
        "directions": "add onion to the cheddar and mozz\r\nadd onion some water and eat",
        "created_date": "08/16/2020 20:57:06",
        "published_date": null,
        "picture": null,
        "author": 2
    },
]
```

In my actions for react-redux, I am getting the data with axios.get(url):

```
export const getAllRecipes = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipe/'); 
  return(
  dispatch({
      type: GET_ALL_RECIPES,
      payload: res.data
    })
  )
}
```

The payload from the function above is put into the store as 'recipes' and added to the below component's props with mapStateToProps

Within one of my component classes, I am trying to create a function that will render information from each recipe by calling map() on the data from the API:

```
class ListRecipes extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllRecipes();
  }

  renderRecipes() {
    return this.props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
      return (
         <div> recipe.(information here) </div>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.renderRecipes()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I then get the error that 'this.props.recipes.map' is not a function.

After some googling, I realized this may be because the data fetched from my API is not in the proper form. I believe it should be an array containing recipe objects. However, in order to see what my data looked like, I tried just rendering JSON.stringify(recipes). Rather than rendering as an array with recipe objects inside, it renders as that list within another list, as below:

```
[
[
    {
        "id":31,
        "title":"marsh",
        "cooktime":"5",
        "ingredients":"marshmellow\r\nonion",
        "directions":"make the onion\r\neat the marsh\r\nenjoy",
        "created_date":"08/16/2020 20:56:09",
        "published_date":null,
        "picture":null,
        "author":3
    },
    ...
]
]
```

Keep in mind I am new to Javascript, so I am not sure if calling JSON.stringify(recipes) actually gives an accurate representation of what the type would look like in Javascript. Please lmk if my method of testing was incorrect.

My question is: what needs to be done to be able be able to turn the output from my API link to be able to be used with the map() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix it, but my fix is pretty sketchy.

As stated above, my response from my API link was a list within a list containing all of the objects I needed. So in theory, I just needed the first and only item of the list and call map() on it. However, that wouldn't work for some reason. If I did that in my 'recipe_list' action, it would just give me the first recipe. If I did it in my component itself with 'props.this.recipes[0]' it would just give me an null variable.

However, calling map on 'props.this.recipes' would only call it one time, and the input parameter was exactly what I needed. So I fixed it by nesting another .map().

I explained that pretty poorly and its probably not the 'correct' way, but here's the code anyways in case it may help:

```
class ListRecipes extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllRecipes();
  }

  renderRecipes() {
    let recipe_nest = this.props.recipes
    return recipe_nest.map((recipes) => {
        return recipes.map((recipe) => {
            return (
              <div> {recipe.(information here)} </div>
            )
        })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.renderRecipes()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```